# Библиотека vk_api для импорта списка audio пользователя вконтакта и альтернативные пути

Tags: python, парсер, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, bs4

Необходимо получать списки аудио пользователей вк, для этого я использую библиотеку vk_api, обеспечивающую работу с api вконтакта:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api import audio
```

Соответствуют ли действительности мои подозрения о том, что эта библиотека использует парсинг страниц с аудио пользователя, а не запрашивает списки аудио через api вконтакта?

В разделе https://vk.com/dev/audio сказано что доступ к публичному API аудиозаписей ограничен и дана ссылка на страницу https://vk.com/dev/audio_api с подробностями, где сказано:

```
1. Как это работает сейчас
Методы для работы с аудиозаписями пользователей и сообществ (audio) доступны для любых приложений, использующих публичный API ВКонтакте. В ответ на запрос сервер отправляет информацию о композиции, включая название, имя исполнителя, ссылку на mp3-файл. Приложение использует эти данные для отображения, воспроизведения и других действий с аудиозаписями.

2. Что изменится
С 16 декабря 2016 года мы отключаем публичный API для работы с аудиозаписями. Существующие методы секции audio будут недоступны для вызова, кроме методов для загрузки аудиофайлов.
```

Первый пункт звучит достаточно противоречиво относительно второго, потому что 2016 уже давно минул и если я правильно понял, то первый пункт уже не о том как работает сейчас, а о том как работало до 2016 года.

При первом использовании vk_api были какие то ошибки с bs4 и правильно ли я понял, что:

**1)** ввиду ограничений api вконтакта на работу с аудио, эта библиотека использует Beautiful Soup 4 для парсинга страниц с аудио пользователя?

**2)** Сам по себе парсинг работает по определению гораздо медленнее, чем могло бы работать через api, если бы такая возможность была, но ее нет и другого пути более быстро получать списки аудио пользователей, чем с помощью библиотеки vk_api (с Beautiful Soup 4) не существует?

Comment: 1) https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/vk_api/audio.py вы поняли все верно
2) написать более быстрый парсер :)

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/519302/

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых,

> Соответствуют ли действительности мои подозрения о том, что эта библиотека использует парсинг страниц с аудио пользователя, а не запрашивает списки аудио через api вконтакта?

- да, библиотека парсит данные из html

Во-вторых, скорее всего, ошибки с bs4 были из-за того, что изменился html-код на странице аудио, и теперь парсинг не работает.

В-третьих, как вариант, использовать библиотеку [vk_audio](https://pypi.org/project/vk-audio/) ( тоже парсит данные из html, только данный способ пока работает)

```
vk = vk_audio.VkAudio(login="login",password="password")
vk.load()#загрузить музыку
your_audio = vk.Audios
print(your_audio[1].title,your_audio[1].url)
```

В-четвертых, если хотите более быстрый вариант api, то можете попробовать подделаться под клиента андроид-приложения:

```
import requests,hashlib,urllib,random,string,re
class VkAndroidApi(object):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers={"User-Agent": "VKAndroidApp/4.13.1-1206 (Android 4.4.3; SDK 19; armeabi; ; ru)","Accept": "image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, */*"}
    def __init__(this,login=None,password=None,token=None,secret=None,v=5.95):
        this.v=v;
        this.device_id = "".join( random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits) for i in range(16))

        if token is not None and secret is not None:
            this.token=token
            this.secret=secret
            return
        #Генерируем рандомный device_id
        answer =  this.session.get(
            "https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&scope=nohttps,audio&client_id=2274003&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username={login}&password={password}".format(
                login=login,
                password=password
            ),
                                   headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; ICS)'}).json()
        if("error" in answer): raise PermissionError("invalid login|password!")
        this.secret = answer["secret"]
        this.token = answer["access_token"]
        #Методы, "Открывающие" доступ к аудио. Без них, аудио получить не получится
        this.method('execute.getUserInfo',func_v=9), 
        this._send('/method/auth.refreshToken?access_token={token}&v={v}&device_id={device_id}&lang=ru'.format(token=this.token,v=v,device_id=this.device_id))
    def method(this,method,**params):
        url =( "/method/{method}?v={v}&access_token={token}&device_id={device_id}".format(method=method,v=this.v,token=this.token,device_id=this.device_id)
            +"".join("&%s=%s"%(i,params[i]) for i in params if params[i] is not None)
        )#генерация ссылки по которой будет генерироваться md5-подпись
        #обратите внимание - в даннаой ссылке нет urlencode параметров 
        return this._send(url,params,method);
    def _send(this,url,params=None,method=None,headers=None):
        hash = hashlib.md5((url+this.secret).encode()).hexdigest()
        if method is not None and params is not None:
            url = ("/method/{method}?v={v}&access_token={token}&device_id={device_id}".format(method=method,token=this.token,device_id=this.device_id,v=this.v)
                + "".join(
                "&"+i+"="+urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(params[i])) for i in params if(params[i] is not None)
                ))
        if headers is None:
            return this.session.get('https://api.vk.com'+url+"&sig="+hash).json()
        else:
            return this.session.get('https://api.vk.com'+url+"&sig="+hash,headers=headers).json()
    _pattern = re.compile(r'/[a-zA-Z\d]{6,}(/.*?[a-zA-Z\d]+?)/index.m3u8()')
    def to_mp3(self,url):
        return self._pattern.sub(r'\1\2.mp3',url)
```

Ну и использование:

```
vk = VkAndroidApi(login="login",password="password")#или token="token",secret="secret"
secret,token = vk.secret,vk.token
audios,playlists = vk.method("execute",code="return [API.audio.get({count:2}),API.audio.getPlaylists({count:1,owner_id:API.users.get()[0].id})];")['response']
#или
audios = vk.method("audio.get",owner_id=100)['response']
```

Comment: большое спасибо, подделка под клиента андроид-приложения оказалась очень эффективной, теперь раздел аудио с 10000 треками забирается за 5 секунд, вместо 25 минут. А какую роль выполняет строчка ```client_id=2274003&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH```? Здесь ключ client_secret для чего нужен и как вы его получили? Статья на хабре, ссылку на которую вы оставляли выше, это ваша статья?

Comment: еще вопрос возник, что делать если вконтакт начал запрашивать капчу? my_unsorted_audio = vk.method("audio.get",owner_id=123456789)#['response'] print(my_unsorted_audio) в ответе приходит {'error': {'error_code': 14, 'error_msg': 'Captcha needed', ...