# Как скачать аудио из вк?

Tags: python

Как скачать аудио из вк? Почему-то скачивает файл m3u8, а мне нужно или mp3, или wav, или flac. Как это сделать, желательно на python.

Comment: в следующий раз, когда будете задавать вопрос, приложите ваш код, чтобы люди смогли воспроизвести, и помочь

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте вот этот код: https://github.com/Sitych/vk_music/blob/master/pikabu.py

Перед этим установите: https://github.com/python273/vk_api : pip3 install vk_api

Comment: vk_api.exceptions.AccessDenied: You don't have permissions to browse -96486711's albums. Мне нужно получить аудио из группы. Это возможно?

Comment: @F1G1 https://vk.com/dev/access_token , получите ключ, и создайте приложение, и да, возможно.

Comment: Даже если группа не моя?

Comment: @F1G1 да, если аудиозаписи открыты, вы можете скачать

Comment: написано, что с 2016 что-то поменялось с аудио, там не описано ни одного метода для работы с ним

Comment: @F1G1 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1179262/Библиотека-vk-api-для-импорта-списка-audio-пользователя-вконтакта-и-альтернативн